# Running two Windows Form application at a time

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

I have two different form applications. One form Application opens my camera and captures my head gesture, and the other application is just a game. Both the program run perfectly separately. All I need to know is how to merge this application. In short I want to run both at a time. The reason is I need to control the game application with my head gesture. There is not any code to add because I have not merge them so no error log as well. Please help me out to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one windows form application which has a single form and include both forms in this app side by side. Make sure that you have all assets to be copied along with the forms otherwise you will face error outputs and design time errors.

adding both forms is into same layout is just by adding them as sub component in your new layout.